# How to partition on a UUID/GUID column in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has 3 Billions rows and 6 TB data in MySQL Aurora and this is expected to grow very rapidly in future 50% increase in a year .

```
CREATE TABLE `AUDIT` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL, UUID
  `CLIENT_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  UUID   
  `OBJECT_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  UUID                                 
  `DATE_TIME` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

we want to partition this table as this is single table and will grow very fast in future.
I am new to data base and we don't have any DBA expert in our team who can help is with this .

I have very specific question about this .

1. On which column we should partition this table ?
   so there are two option that we have

   a. CLIENT_ID (10K distinct clients and query will never happen across the client )

   b. OBJECT_ID (700 millions case but 90 % of the select happen based on this )

We are thinking to partition based on client so that because of few big client other small client should not get impacted .

2. My UUID is in sorted manner so is there anyway partition can be created
3. Instead of native partition can we create different small tables which will be better ?
4. we have limitation with MySQL partition that partition column should be part of primary key but in our case we don't have ,How can we over come that problem ? Will clustered index in this case ?

**Update Question based on comments**

So the 90 % of the time we look up by OBJECT_ID a key search and that return 99% of the time 10 to 100 values .
UUID example (6tgbcrq9pkjfnezsdo82mcrzz) is not Mysql generated id its generated by our application
We are on MySQL 5.7 but can migrate to 8 if that would give us some real benifit .
No Join on this table

We have already Index on Primary key default and CLIENT_ID and OBJECT_ID.
Most common access pattern is on OBJECT_ID ,But if we create partition then select might have to go 700 millions partition not sure need to know why it is advised to create partition on OBJECT_ID int this case ?

We also query based on CLIENT_ID like where CLIENT_ID='6tgbcrqskjfhsd78o82mcrzz' but 90 % or 95% of the time we search based on OBJECT_ID like OBJECT_ID='6tgbcrq9pkjfnezsdo82mcrzz'
ID is not for joining the table its for look up as well .

There is no such performance issue we are facing because of the partition but its one big table doing and DDL is very difficult and later of we plan to migrate to some other version or data store it will be even problematic .

In Future we might perform join as well but as of now no join on this table .

Exact DDL

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123669/discussion-on-question-by-anupam-how-to-partition-on-a-uuid-guid-column-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

There is a hard limit of 8K partitions.  The practical limit is about 50.  I see no benefit in `PARTITIONing`.

My blob on UUIDs is somewhat irrelevant since you have your own UUIDs.

If most of the queries are `SELECT ... WHERE object_id = '...'`, then having the `PRIMARY KEY` start with `object_id` would help performance the most.

Case 1:  The combination of object_id and client_id is unique:

- Drop id
- Change to `PRIMARY KEY(object_id, client_id)`

Case 2:  `id` is needed to provide uniqueness:

Change the PK to these two:

```
PRIMARY KEY(object_id, id),
INDEX(id)
```

Case 3:  If id is needed, but it does not need to be a UUID:, change to `BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT` and do as in case 2.  (BIGINT is 8 bites, a lot smaller than what you seem to have now.)  Note that AUTO_INCREMENT lets you insert rows without specifying id; a number will be generated for you.  This allows multiple clients insert rows without worry about dups.

All 3 cases will improve performance because the 10-100 rows can be fetched more efficiently.

What you have:  Well you don't even have an index on object_id, so it needs to scan the table.  Simply adding an index would help immensely.

Addin an index would speed up the operation; then there would be up to 10-100 disk reads to get a resultset.

What I recommend:  My suggestion further speeds things up by "clustering" the 10-100 rows "consecutively" in the table, thereby leading to 1-2 blocks needing to be read from disk.